# Can we reverse engineer binlog with row format to make MySQL AES_ENCRYPT visible?

Tags: encryption, databases, mysql

Suppose if I am using the mysql database based encryption using AES_ENCRYPT function & insert records, is it possible to decode the row formatted binlogs generated by MySQL to obtain the actual statements consisting of AES_ENCRYPT?

Comment: Function AES_ENCRYPT() in MySQL is insecure because it operates in ECB block mode. Furthermore, it doesn't assure authenticity.

Answer (score 1):

There is a description of what MySQL does [here](https://polarssl.org/kb/how-to/emulate-mysql-aes-encrypt-and-aes-decrypt-in-polarssl). It takes the key almost as is and applies AES in [ECB mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29), which is weak since it leaks which blocks are identical to each other in data encrypted with a given key. You should not assume that data which was encrypted with MySQL's [`AES_ENCRYPT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt) is really "secure".

That being said, whether your key and data will make it to the binary log depends on how it was configured. If using statement-based formatting, then the binary log will contain the *SQL statements* which were issued (at least those which entail modifications), and your data and key may be revealed that way. If you use row-based formatting, then the log contains the *results* (alterations to actual rows), and your cleartext data and key won't appear in the log. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014290/if-i-do-encryption-decryption-in-mysql-as-opposed-to-in-the-application-will) for pointers.

Comment: I too agree its not secure & I know about row-based formatting. My question is can we reverse engineer the row-formatted binary logs to extract the data out. for e.g. as mentioned in http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/05/06/debugging-problems-with-row-based-replication/